# How to select dropdown menu in python using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I want to know how can I select the option from dropdown list from website.

The html is here

```
<thead>
    <td style="width: 40%;">
        <select name="product_size" id="sct-size" data-md-selectize>
            <option value="-">Choose Size</option>
                                                    <option value="323">XS</option>
                                                    <option value="324">S</option>
                                                    <option value="325">M</option>
                                                    <option value="326">L</option>
                                                    <option value="327">XL</option>
                                                    <option value="328">XXL</option>
                                                    <option value="342">1 years old</option>
                                                    <option value="343">5 years old</option>
                                                    <option value="344">8 years old</option>
                                                    <option value="345">12 years old</option>
                                                </select>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 40%;">
        <select name="product_color" id="sct-color" data-md-selectize>
            <option value="-">Choose Color</option>
                                                    <option value="594">N/A</option>
                                                </select>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 19%;"><input type="text" class="md-input" name="product_stock_" id="inp-stock" placeholder="Stock" style="margin-top: -11px;text-align: center;"/></td>
    <td style="width: 1%;"><a href="#" id="btn-addstock" style="margin-top: 5px; display: block;" title="Add Stock"><i class="material-icons">&#xE148;</i></a></td>
</thead>
```

I want to select the "Choose Size" then "S" option. I tried this code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

mySelect = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("sct-size"))
mySelect.select_by_visible_text("S")
```

But got the error

> NoSuchElementException: Message: Could not locate element with visible text: S

I already looked many solution regard to this problem here on stackoverflow. Its suppose to select the "S" from dropdown menu but didn't. I don't know what else I can try.

Thanks.

already tried

1. https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12029/how-do-i-work-with-dropdowns-in-selenium-webdriver
2. [Select a dropdown using Python + Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51008054/select-a-dropdown-using-python-selenium)

## Edited 1

I also tried

```
mySelect = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("sct-size"))
mySelect.select_by_value("323")
```

but got this error

> NoSuchElementException: Message: Cannot locate option with value: 323

Also I tried to change the find_element method with name

```
obj = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('product_size'))
obj.select_by_index(1)
```

and got error

> NoSuchElementException: Message: Cannot locate option with index 1

Perhaps the find_element is the problem? I don't know.

## Edited 2

I tired to play around with 'inspect' tool in google chrome and found that when the page load, the html only load 1 option (which in this case, its 'Choose Size'). This explain why the error.

html code when the page load.

```
<thead>
<td style="width: 40%;">
    <select name="product_size" id="sct-size" data-md-selectize>
        <option value="-">Choose Size</option>                                                    
</td>
<td style="width: 40%;">
    <select name="product_color" id="sct-color" data-md-selectize>
        <option value="-">Choose Color</option>
                                                
                                            </select>
</td>
<td style="width: 19%;"><input type="text" class="md-input" name="product_stock_" id="inp-stock" placeholder="Stock" style="margin-top: -11px;text-align: center;"/></td>
<td style="width: 1%;"><a href="#" id="btn-addstock" style="margin-top: 5px; display: block;" title="Add Stock"><i class="material-icons">&#xE148;</i></a></td>
</thead>
```

Tried Seema Nair solution but got other error

> AttributeError: 'Select' object has no attribute 'click'

my new code is

```
mySelect = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("sct-size")) 
mySelect.click() 
mySelect.select_by_visible_text("S")
```

So, new question, how can i click dropdown to let the option code reveal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original code selecting by visible text or value will work.

I faced a similar issue and this was because,  before selecting the value from the drop down, I had to do a click on the dropdown link and then perform the select.

So add a click method before the Select and the same code you had initially will work.

Comment: So, i tried but got another error. AttributeError: 'Select' object has no attribute 'click'..

Comment: mySelect = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("sct-size"))
mySelect.click()
mySelect.select_by_visible_text("S")

Comment: i update my question based on what you suggest on 'Edited 2'

Comment: Just try to adjust my code and you right. Thank a lot.

Comment: I am glad,  i could help. Good luck!